# Python Tkinter - How add a notebook class into a tk.toplevel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to have a notebook class because I want to create frames instances and then add to it. The problem is that ttk.Notebook needs the root window and I don't know how to give him the top-level root master.

That's the code:

```
class Notebook:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.notebook=ttk.Notebook(parent) #if i give this, the program will add the notebook to the main window
        self.notebook.grid(row=1,column=0)

    def add_tab(self,title):
        frame=ttk.Frame(self.notebook,width=1280, height=280)
        frame.pack(fill='both',expand=True)
        self.notebook.add(frame,text=title)
        tx=tk.Text(frame)
        tx.pack()

class MainChat(tk.Toplevel): 
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.master=parent
        self.title("Test")
        self.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
        self.resizable(False,False)
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.createwidg()

    def createwidg(self):
        self.titlelb=ttk.Label(self,text="Test",font=("Helvetica",16))
        self.nb1=Notebook(self.master)

        self.titlelb.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=(10,0))
        
        self.nb1.add_tab('Test')
```

Comment: `Notebook(self.master)` should be `Notebook(self)`.

Comment: Now it gives me a typeerror in the  notebook init class: TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe now you have different problem - and it would need to create new question on new page.

Comment: I created minimal working code and I got your new error - problem is because your `class Notebook` is NOT real tkinter widget and it doesn't need `super().__init__(parent)` but `super().__init__()` or even you could skip this `super().__init__()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem: you need

```
 Notebook(self)
```

without `.master`

---

Second problem: your `class Notebook` is not real tkinter widget so it doesn't need `super().__init__(parent)` but standard `super().__init__()`. And even you can skip this line.

---

Minimal working code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Notebook:
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        #super().__init__(parent)  # no need it
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(parent)
        self.notebook.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def add_tab(self, title):
        frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook, width=1280, height=280)
        frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.notebook.add(frame, text=title)

        tx = tk.Text(frame)
        tx.pack()


class MainChat(tk.Toplevel):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.master = parent
        self.title("Test")
        #self.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.createwidg()

    def createwidg(self):
        self.titlelb = ttk.Label(self, text="Test", font=("Helvetica", 16))
        self.titlelb.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(10, 0))
        
        self.nb1 = Notebook(self)  # without `.master`
        self.nb1.add_tab('Test')
        

def run():
    MainChat(root)


if __name__ == '__main__':        
    root = tk.Tk()
    b = tk.Button(root, text="Chat", command=run)
    b.grid(row=0, column=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:**

[PEP 8 -- StyleGuide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

ie. spaces around `=`, space after `,`